# What are the prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, gaussian-integers

Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ be prime. I am trying to determine all prime ideals $\mathfrak{q} \subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $\mathfrak{q} \cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}$. I know that

$$
\{\text{prime ideals }\mathfrak{q} \subset \mathbb{Z}[i] \text{ s.t. } \mathfrak{q} \cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}\}
$$

is bijective to

$$
\{\text{prime ideals in } \mathbb{Z}[i] \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)\}.
$$

But how can explicitely determine all $\mathfrak{q}$?

Comment: How would you determine the prime ideals of $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+1)$?

Comment: @Mindlack I do not know.

Comment: Prime ideals (ee the duplicate):

 1. $(p)$ is a prime ideal  if $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ is a rational prime
 2. $(p)=(\pi_1)(\pi_2)$ with conjugate (and distinct) prime ideals $(\pi_1)$ and $(\pi_2)$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$
 3. $(2)=(1+i)^2$ is the square of a prime ideal.